# incrementing hash map count in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have the function below. However, when I pass a string to it, I get the following error:

`error: operator call corresponds to a dot-qualified call 'charCountMap.get(c).plus(1)' which is not allowed on a nullable receiver 'charCountMap.get(c)'. charCountMap.put(c, charCountMap.get(c) + 1)`

```
private fun characterCount(inputString:String) {
  val charCountMap = HashMap<Char, Int>()
  val strArray = inputString.toCharArray()
  for (c in strArray)
  {
    if (charCountMap.containsKey(c))
    {
      charCountMap.put(c, charCountMap.get(c) + 1)
    }
    else
    {
      charCountMap.put(c, 1)
    }
  }
  
  
}
```

Comment: The `get`-method returns a nullable value. Try `(charCountMap.get(c) ?: 0) + 1`.

Comment: Try: charCountMap.put(c, charCountMap.getValue(c) + 1)

Answer (score 3):

The Kotlin Standard Library has [`groupingBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/grouping-by.html) and [`eachCount`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/each-count.html) for this purpose, you don't need to do any of this manually:

```
private fun characterCount(inputString:String) {
    val charCountMap : Map<Char, Int> = inputString.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
}
```

Note that I put the type on charCountMap for clarity, but it can be left off and inferred.

Comment: As an extension function: `fun String.characterCount() = groupingBy { it }.eachCount()`

Answer (score 2):

There is nice [compute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method in `HashMap` for this:

```kotlin
private fun characterCount(inputString:String) = hashMapOf<Char, Int>().also { charCountMap ->
    inputString.forEach { charCountMap.compute(it) { _, v -> if (v == null) 1 else v + 1 } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the other answers are correct. [Todd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66874750/1225617) is right, you don't need to write a function for this. Just use the standard library. And if you are going to write a function that updates maps, [Михаил Нафталь's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872859/1225617) to use `compute()` to handle updating existing values is also good.

---

However, if you're just doing this an an exercise, here are three suggestions to fix/improve your algorithm:

1. Instead of `get()`, use [`getValue()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-value.html), which does not return null. It will raise an exception if the element does not exist, but you already checked for that.
2. Use the `[]` operator instead of `put()` (no need to, it's just nicer syntax).
3. You don't need to call `toCharArray()` because Strings are already iterable.

```kotlin
if (charCountMap.containsKey(c))
{
    charCountMap[c] = charCountMap.getValue(c) + 1
}
else
{
    charCountMap[c] = 1
}
```

---

Rewriting the whole thing using standard formatting:

```
fun characterCount(inputString: String): Map<Char, Int> {
    val charCountMap = mutableMapOf<Char, Int>()
    for (c in inputString) {
        if (charCountMap.containsKey(c)) {
            charCountMap[c] = charCountMap.getValue(c) + 1
        } else {
            charCountMap[c] = 1
        }
    }
    return charCountMap
}
```